# Websockets not working on Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, websocket

I have a server in PHP which binds to a port and listens to sockets. My server is started in a PHP script with:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
```

It then listens to the port:

```
socket_listen($socket);
```

When a HTTP message arrives from the client, the server reads the header:

```
$header = socket_read($socket_new,1024);
```

and then stores the connection in a Memcache storage. This works for most browsers including safari, firefox and Chrome's Canary. However, it doesn't work on chrome. The browser throws an error message:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://xyz.com:9001/chat_server.php'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect
>   'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

My version of Chrome is: Version 38.0.2125.111 m (64-bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same issue and we could solve it by increasing the "maximum number of bytes" parameter in the socket_read() function. You can try

```
socket_tead($socket_new, 2048);
```

The reason is that websocket header in chrome sometimes is greater that 1024 bytes. So, when your server reads 1024 bytes, it does not get Sec-Websocket-Key parameter and it can not generate valid Sec-Websocket-Accept value.

You can also use fsockopen() and fread() instead of socket_read() function.

Comment: in my case, max. number of bytes = 5000 worked.
socket_read($socket_new, 5000);